# Using moment-duration-format plugin inside Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm trying to use the [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plugin to format my MomentJS durations. How would I go about using this plugin in my Angular controllers? Seems like it should work out of the box once the JS has been imported, but it's not.

I've imported momentJS and MDF JS file in my index.html:

```
// MomentJS
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
// moment-duration-format plugin
<script src="bower_components/moment-duration-format/lib/moment-duration-format.js"></script>
```

But when I call the below line in a controller, I get an error:

```
console.log( moment.duration(123, "minutes").format("h:mm") );
```

Error:

```
TypeError: moment.duration(...).format is not a function...
```

Comment: I have the same issue in an Angular2 app where I'm trying to use moment-duration-format in a filter, but it's not loaded correctly.  Loading scripts the same, Same error as you...

Answer (score 0):

Include your lib file of moment in your app, for example in routes file adding in the files section and then you just need to call it like

console.log("moment -> ", moment());